# Stroke width seen only in Isolation Mode in Illustrator CC2017

Tags: adobe-illustrator, color, vector, stroke, appearance

I am using the curvature tool and setting the stroke to 10 pt. But the line appears to be as thin as possible. Even if I change the color of the stroke, it is not seen. All the characteristics- the width and the color- appear only when I double click on the object and enter the Isolation Mode. I am using Adobe Illustrator CC2017. However, this problem is only seen in this file and it was not there earlier as well. Is there a setting I might have enabled by mistake? How to fix this?[image: Outside Isolation Mode (top image) , Inside Isolation Mode (bottom image)]

Answer (score 4):

You are in View > Outline mode. Change to Preview mode to see full strokes and fills. The mode is shown in  workspace tab headers in your screenshot.